# Averaging scores of same type in an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, average

Suppose I have a sample array that looks like this:

```
color_values = [{'score': 3, 'color': u'blue'}, {'score': 1, 'color': u'red'}, {'score': 4, 'color': u'green'}, {'score': 4, 'color': u'red'}, {'score': 2, 'color': u'blue'}]
```

How do I write a code in python for a new array which averages the score of all the same colors? So the new array would look like:

```
color_values = [{'score': 2.5, 'color': u'blue'}, {'score': 2.5, 'color': u'red'}, {'score': 4, 'color': u'green'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest (if not the shortest) way to solve this kind of problem is to build a `dict` from the key to a list of values, and then aggregate it:

```
by_color = {}
for obj in color_values:
    by_color.setdefault(obj['color'], []).append(obj['score'])
color_values = [{'score': float(sum(value)) / len(value), 'color': key}
                for key, value in by_color.items()]
```

Comment: You can keep track of just the sum and the number of items, no need to keep track of all the items.

Comment: Thanks! How would you modify this to ignore averaging score values of a certain value, say 0?

Comment: @ono `sum` and `len` can take a comprehension e.g. `sum(v for v in value if v != 0)`.

Comment: Great. Also, how would you flip the order of the elements so it's [{'color': u'blue', 'score': 3]} instead of [{'score': 3, 'color':u u'blue'}]?

Comment: @ono3 you can't; the order of iteration of `dict` keys is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension:

```
average = lambda l: sum(l) / float(len(l))
[{'score': average([d['score'] for d in color_values if d['color'] is color]),
  'color': color} for color in set(d['color'] for d in color_values)]
```

Output:

```
>>> color_values = [{'score': 3, 'color': u'blue'}, {'score': 1, 'color': u'red'}, {'score': 4, 'color': u'green'}, {'score': 4, 'color': u'red'}, {'score': 2, 'color': u'blue'}]
>>> average = lambda l: sum(l) / float(len(l))
>>> [{'score': average([d['score'] for d in color_values if d['color'] is color]),
...   'color': color} for color in set(d['color'] for d in color_values)]
[{'color': u'blue', 'score': 2.5}, {'color': u'green', 'score': 4.0}, {'color': u'red', 'score': 2.5}]
```

Comment: It's not averaging the scores. It looks like it's finding the first one and just using that.

Comment: Are you sure? Using your input above, I get precisely the output you specify.

Comment: Just re-did it and I'm still just getting the original set. Not sure how you're getting different results. Your averaged output is the new color_values, right?

Comment: Ah, it does work. I was looking at the wrong set. I needed to assign 'color_values = [{'score': average([d['score'] for d in color_values if d['color'] is color]),
  'color': color} for color in set(d['color'] for d in color_values)]'